# Cloudflare page rules, SSL on one page only

Tags: http, ssl, https, cloudflare

SSL flexible is ON.
Rules:

```
http://example.com/register - Always use https
https://example.com/* - Forwarding to http://example.com/$1
```

I try to enable SSL only in one page, the rest should be http.

Comment: It's a good idea to wants to protect the register page with https. But if the whole website don't use https, it's vulnerable to sslstrip. You should think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Page Rules stop at the entry that they match and do not continue on (eg, if a rule matches, it will not match anything else below) you will want to make a "dummy" rule in the middle of the "Always use HTTPS" and the "downgrader" as shown below:

[image]

It may also be better rather than using page rules for this but to do the redirection on server side. You can use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header that CloudFlare will set to tell if a user is using HTTP or HTTPS